# Pybind11 build with poetry

Tags: static-libraries, pybind11, python-poetry, linker-flags

I am currently trying to build a small pybind11 extension and to integrate smoothly with our current setup, it would be neat if that would work with `poetry build && poetry install`

```
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext

def build(setup_kwargs):
    ext_modules = [
        Pybind11Extension(
            "my_module",
            ["folder/one.cpp", "folder/another.cpp"],
            include_dirs=[".", "my_static_lib/include/"],
            extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-pthread'],
            language='c++',
            cxx_std=11
        ),
    ]
    setup_kwargs.update({
        "ext_modules": ext_modules,
        "cmd_class": {"build_ext": build_ext},
        "zip_safe": False,
    })
```

That compiles all fine, but since I don't know how to inform the linker about the static library that I depend on, I have undefined symbols when I load the package.
Any idea how that works?
Is this an odd thing to try?
Thanks for your help or comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually quite simple, I just did not find the documentation anywhere. There is an argument called "extra_link_args", where I can specify all these things:

```css
def build(setup_kwargs):
    ext_modules = [
        Pybind11Extension(
            "my_module",
            ["folder/one.cpp", "folder/another.cpp"],
            include_dirs=[".", "my_static_lib/include/"],
            extra_compile_args=['-O3'],
            extra_link_args=['my_static_lib/libmystatic.a', '-lbz2', '-pthread'],
            language='c++',
            cxx_std=11
        ),
    ]
    setup_kwargs.update({
        "ext_modules": ext_modules,
        "cmd_class": {"build_ext": build_ext},
        "zip_safe": False,
    })
```

I still haven't figured out how do specify the compiler, but fortunately, it works for now with the default compiler on my mac.